# Nuxt: Set arbitrary page metadata that can be accessed anywhere in the application

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm migrating from Vue to include Nuxt (v2). Previously I'd add metadata to my Router (see below).

I could access `$route.meta` from anywhere within my application without having to coordinate a new `Vuex` store.

Is there a way to do this equivalent in Nuxt? Can I add arbitrary metadata to a page somehow?

```
{
   path: '/',
   component: MyComponent,
   meta: {
      breadcrumbs: [...]
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not use Vuex here? Pretty much the same as the router (can be used anywhere). Otherwise, you could put it into localStorage, window or overcharge Vue's instance. Meanwhile, I'm not sure the last 2 solutions are good in terms of performance, it may cause some memory leaks regarding how SSR works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom component property `meta` for that.

To define a meta property:

```js
export default {
  meta: {
    myProperty: "the value"
  }
}
```

Accessing `myProperty` inside any component:

```js
this.$route.meta.myProperty
```

Check this another example https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1687#issuecomment-331870619

Comment: no matter what I put in the meta property, `this.$route.meta` always equals `[{}]`.